# What is the role of "would " in the following sentences and what do they mean?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, expressions, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I read these sentences in an English learning guide. Please let me know what is the role of  "would" in the following sentences and what they mean:

> 1. Son, I want someone would tell you that you are lazy.
> 2. Is there any body here who would help me about the hospital?
> 3. It would be better if he would know regarding his mistakes.
> 4. It is  better if he would know regarding his mistakes.

Comment: I question the correctness (qua English) of each of these four sentences.

Comment: Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].